# Why is my flutter app id missing when it is asking for an autofill entry on android?

Tags: android, flutter, autofill

I'm trying to implement an autofill feature to my loginForm in my app. It works well and asks the user to save the password but when it does (or when it is requesting the entry) the app id is missing and the password manager I use (keepass2Android) shows "Androidapp://" instead of "Androidapp://com.developer.appID". When I take a look at what netflix does it requests an entry for "androidapp://com.netflix.mediaclient"

I have tried looking at other stackoverflow questions, asking chatgpt, looking into the android and flutter documentation but haven't found any "autofill app id configs". Or anything similar to that matter. Everybody seems to have problems with the autofill itselves which works but not the app id which is missing.

Here is the code for my login form:

```
/*some structural code*/
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
                controller: _urlController,
                autocorrect: false,
              ),
            AutofillGroup(child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                    autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.username],
                    controller: _usernameController,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    autocorrect: false,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                controller: _passwordController,
                autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password],
                autocorrect: false,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              ),
            ],
            )),
            LoginSubmitButton(
              formKey: _formKey,
              usernameController: _usernameController,
              passwordController: _passwordController,
              urlController: _urlController,
              setHomeWidget: setHomeWidget,
            ),
      //... other code
      /*loginSubmitButton.onpressed has
       TextInput.finishAutofillContext();
      */
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tomprotiva.autojidelna">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <application
        android:label="autojidelna"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle in app directory:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.tomprotiva.autojidelna"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 155
        versionName '1.1.1'
    }
    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).